# removeAttr() on multiple elements at once

Tags: jquery, methods

I have been playing around with this and so far have not found anywhere that address' it so may as well ask. I am using jQuery's removeAttr() method on multiple elements but the attribute to be removed on the elements is the same, I just want to strip out the jQuery applied styles like so:

```
div1.removeAttr('style');
div2.removeAttr('style');
div3.removeAttr('style');
div4.removeAttr('style');
```

is there a way to combine this into one statement that looks cleaner? Id rather not combine them all into an array and loop through since it will just make the code more complex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have a uniform class in your HTML like

```
<div class="nostyle" style="background-color:red;">1</div>
<div class="nostyle" style="background-color:blue;">2</div>
```

Then it is simple to remove them all with one JQuery selector like this

```
$('.nostyle').removeAttr('style');
```

You could use this selector `$('div')` for all divs on the page, but that's not a great idea if want to use some other divs with inline styles. Best to specify with a CSS class.

Comment: Thanks, I must be working too hard for it not to dawn on me to use a class selector, this was the most helpful answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use a common selector as a class or if for some reason you have to use variables, you can [add](http://api.jquery.com/add/) each element in matched set:

```
div1.add(div2).add(div3).add(div4).removeAttr('style');
```

Comment: I just learned jquery.add() from you. I didn't realize you could build a new JQuery object this way.

Comment: @ThisClark It is sometimes useful but usually not really... ;)

Answer (score 1):

`$('.divs').removeAttr('style');`